How do I prove the closure of the image of T is uniformly bounded?
I know that Peano's theorem for the existence of local solutions of the Cauchy Problem
$$y'(x) = f(x,y(x)) \hspace{30pt} y(x_0) =y_0$$
where $f \in C(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n)$, $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R \times R}^n$ is an open set and $(x_0,y_0) \in \Omega$ are the initial values, can be proved using the Schauder's fixed point theorem for normed spaces. In particular, defining the operator
$$Ty(x) := y_0 + \int_{x_0} ^{x} f(t,y(t))dt,$$
$y$ is a solution of the Cauchy problem if and only if it is a fixed point of $T$, that is iff $Ty = y$. If we restrict $T$ to the set
$$X := \bigg\{ y \in C([x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta],\mathbb{R}^n) \hspace{5pt} \big | \hspace{5pt}|| y - (x \mapsto y_0)||_\infty \leq \epsilon, \hspace{3pt} y(x_0) = y_0  \bigg\}$$
where $x \mapsto y_0$ is the constant function to $y_0$, it's easy to prove that $X$ is closed, convex and nonempty; after finding a suitable $\delta$ and compact sets inside $\Omega$, we can show that $T:X\to X$. Using this/these compact sets, we can prove with some uniform estimates of $f$, that $T$ is (even uniformly) continuous with respect to the sup norm $\| \cdot \|_\infty$. For the Schauder's theorem hypotheses to be completely  verified it remains to be proved that  $\overline{T(X)}$ is compact inside $X$. This can be accomplished using the Ascoli-Arzelà's theorem for metric spaces: the closure of the image is automatically a closed set of $X$, $T(X)$ can be shown to be equicontinuous using the maximum of the continuous function $f$ on some compact sets inside $\Omega$, thus its closure is equicontinuous too (a general property)...
But how can I prove that $\overline{T(X)}$ is uniformly bounded inside $X$?

Let $y \in X$ and $y_0$ be the constant function $x \mapsto y_0$. For $x \geq x_0$:
$$
\left|y(x) - y_0\right| = \left| \int_{x_0}^x f(t, y(t)) dt \right| \leq
\int_{x_0}^x \left|f(t, y(t))\right| dt \leq (x - x_0) \cdot \sup_{t \in [x_0, x]} \left|f(t, y(t))\right|.
$$
Since $\left\|y - y_0 \right\|_\infty \leq \varepsilon$ and $|x - x_0| \leq \delta$ by construction,
$$\left\{(t, y(t)) \mid t \in [x_0, x]\right\} \subset 
[x_0, x] \times [y_0 - \varepsilon, y_0 + \varepsilon] \subset 
[x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta] \times [y_0 - \varepsilon, y_0 + \varepsilon] = \Pi.$$
It means that
$$
\sup_{t \in [x_0, x]} \left|f(t, y(t))\right| \leq \sup_{(t, s) \in \Pi} \left|f(t, s)\right| = C < \infty,
$$
because $f \in C(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\Pi$ is a compact set. Repeating the same for $x < x_0$, we get
$$
|y(x) - y_0| \leq C \cdot |x - x_0| \leq C \cdot \delta, \quad x \in [x_0-\delta, x_0 + \delta],
$$
so $\left\|y - y_0\right\|_\infty \leq C \delta$, and $\|y\|_\infty \leq \left\|y - y_0\right\|_\infty + \|y_0\|_\infty \leq C \delta + |y_0|$.
So, $T(X)$ is a bounded set in $X$, hence $\overline{T(X)}$ is bounded as well.
